# Opencv on android and video record

Tags: android, opencv, video, record

I'm trying to process camera image on opencv(2.4.8) and record video together on android.

In the middle of just camera preview, video record is done successfully, however, after starting

image process on opencv, there is EXCEPTION like below. It is not functional videowriter API in opnecv on android, so I used MediaRecorder that is android API to record video.

Is there any way I can solve the problems were occurred by when trying to process image and video record at the same time?

Thanks!

```
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at android.hardware.Camera.access$600(Camera.java:133)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:815)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4961)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
02-24 16:38:50.071: E/AndroidRuntime(8117):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```